# Implementing Map Rotation in ArcGIS for Android?

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I am trying to rotate the map as the orientation of the device is changed. What I want is the map should always point towards the north regardless of the orientation of the device.

Like Suppose, If I gradually rotate my device to x degrees, The map should accordingly rotate to -x degrees keeping the map facing in the same direction as it was earlier.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? figuring out the rotation, or actually rotating the map?

Comment: Once you get the compass direction, you can set the rotation of the my by using this: https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html#setRotationAngle%28double,%20com.esri.core.geometry.Point,%20boolean%29

Comment: Actually I was thinking about some kind of listener which will keep on changing the map orientation as the device orientation changes.

Comment: I'm still not sure what point you are currently stuck in. Please edit the question, and provide as many details as necessary

Comment: @DevDatta I want to capture the event when the user rotates the device and change the angle of the map accordingly.

Comment: Your question is still quite unclear. Please share all that you have already done, and where you are stuck. Please see this post for more details: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question

Comment: I am really not getting what is unclear in this question.Still  I will put it in other words. I have a simple query.. How can I keep my map always pointing towards the north direction regardless of the screen orientation. Hope this makes sense.